# Static Front Page not working for custom theme

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I'm building a custom theme for a client... I am trying to set up a static front page, but no matter what page I select it falls back to a custom post type archive page.  I have confirmed that I can set other static pages to templates like my About page, but if I set my About page as the static home page it just falls back to `archive-project.php`.

```
<?php
/**
 * @author    Mark Abel
 * @package   clientname/home
 * @version   1.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
get_header(); ?>
<?php /* Template Name: Home */ ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'partials/partial', 'sidenav' );?>

<section class="masonry__container" id="masonry__container">
  <div class="masonry" id="masonry">
    <?php
      if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <?php 
            $project_for = get_post_meta($post->ID, "project_for", true); 
            $has_video = (get_post_meta($post->ID, "has_video", true));
            $hide_single_link = (get_post_meta($post->ID, "hide_single_link", true));
          ?>
          <article class="masonry__tile" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <img src=<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?> alt="an image" />
              <div class="masonry__overlay"><div class="masonry__title">
                <?php echo get_the_title() ?>
              </div>
              <div class="masonry__project">
                <?php echo $project_for ?>
              </div>
              <span></span>
              <?php if ($hide_single_link) : ?>
                <a class="masonry__cta masonry__video" href=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "video_link", true) ?>>Play video</a>
              <?php else :  ?>
                <div class="masonry__cta"><a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>">Click to view</a></div>
              <?php endif ?>
              <?php if ($has_video and !$hide_single_link) : ?>
                <a class="masonry__video" href=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "video_link", true) ?>>Play video</a>
              <?php endif ?>
            </div>
          </article>
        <?php endwhile;
      endif;
      wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
  </div>
</section>

</body>

<!-- Footer --> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>

</html>
```

Comment: Does your theme have a `front-page.php` template?

Comment: I added one and it still didn't work.  The main page is falling back to my ```archive-project.php``` which I find puzzling since I have an ```archive.php```.  It's also adding the class ```active-menu``` to the link in my ` header menu

Comment: When I switch to ```2019 theme``` it works as expected.  Are there any hooks or functions that could be overriding this functionality?

Comment: Yes, there are hooks like `template_include` for overriding certain templates. Try searching for that in the theme functions file? It's also possible that the main query has been changed and it wasn't reset; e.g. using `wp_reset_query()` or `wp_reset_postdata()`. So once again, check your `functions.php` file for any suspicious functions/code.

Comment: All of my queries have ```wp_reset_postdata()``` at the end of them.  I didn't find any code in my theme with ```template_include```.

Comment: What could cause my root to A. not display a static page when explicitly told to do so and B. fall back to an archive page for a specific custom post type?  The second part really confuses me.

Comment: Just to confirm: 1) You used the "Reading" settings page to set the static front page, right? 2) When you select a page from the drop-down there, does the selection actually get saved? But if you can share your `functions.php` code, then perhaps we can help you identify the source of the problem.

Comment: Another strange thing is the 'Projects' custom post type in my Nav Menu always has the ```active-menu``` class when I'm on the root.

Comment: I set the page in reading.  I was successfully able to get the correct code loaded when I used a ```front-page.php``` and toggled settings to 'show recent posts'

Comment: My ```functions.php``` is just used to import a bunch of other files...

Comment: Static pages still won't work and I confirmed they are saving.

Comment: Well then, the issue could be with one of the imported files.. because this is certainly a theme issue since the 2019 theme works just fine.. you'll need to find the code in the custom theme which is causing the issue - you can try commenting out a code then check if that helps.

Comment: Bingo.  I had added a hook to always show the projects archive on the main page and had forgotten about it.